# how to get value of select field in django without any forms.py

Tags: django

I want to get value of this select field. But do not have any forms. How to get value of select field in django without any forms.py ?

```
<label>Portal Language:</label>
<select name="language">
    {% get_available_languages as LANGUAGES %}
    {% for lang in LANGUAGES %}
        <option>
            {{ lang.1 }}
        </option>
    {% end for %}
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

add these in the views.py

views.py

```
 class ClientCreateView(View):
     def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

          language = request.POST.get('language')
```

Answer (score 0):

Functional implementation with more safer version:

In your view that handles this request, do it like this `selected_lang = request.POST.get('language', None)`

Assuming your view is:

```
def get_language(request):
    selected_lang = request.POST.get('language', None)
#do whatever you want to do with this selected_lang
```